# JetBrains: Sort a file alphabetically based on first letter of each line

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ or PyCharm

I have huge constants file and want to be able to easily read through it alphabetically.

Comment: Under the Edit menu look for "Sort Lines"? What version are you using, do you have the String manipulation plugin installed?

Answer (score 28):

Edit-> Sort Lines as my amigo above stated!